# Change all elments in lists of lists

Tags: python

I have list of n list like :

```
tab = [[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
       [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]

def vnor(tab):
    for x in tab:
        if type(x) == int:
            x = 1
        elif type(x) == list:
            vnor(x)
    return tab
```

and  I would like to have

```
[[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]],[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]]
```

Comment: What does `vnor` mean?

Comment: can you explain more in detail what is it that you want?

Comment: `x` is just a local variable here.  Assigning to `x` changes nothing other than `x`, it has no connection to the list that the value was retrieved from.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: C’mon guys this is perfectly understandable question.

Comment: If the list you're interested in always has the same number of levels as `tab` then you can use a nested list comprehension:
`[[[1 for x in y] for y in z] for z in tab]`.

Granted this might not be super readable, but it gets the job done efficiently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to overwrite the elements:

```py
tab = [[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]
def vnor(tab):
    for index,x in enumerate(tab):
        if type(x) == int:
            tab[index] = 1
        elif type(x) == list:
            vnor(x)
    return tab
vnor(tab)
```

Comment: I like kind and patient people like you ... thanks for making this community more awesome!

Comment: @adirabargil I hope you are doing the same.

Comment: I do my best!...